# Listbox is inaccessible due to its protection level Error in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to add some text to a listBox in a form, from another form, but I get red underlines in the code that should add to the listBox. Isn't it possible to pass data to a form in a class from another class that I'm trying to do? I'm using VisualStudio 2013

I have this code I'm using in the MainForm class:

```
    // Local object of SearchResultForm
    SearchResultForm frmSearchResult = new SearchResultForm();
    frmSearchResult.Show();
    frmSearchResult.listBox.IsEnabled == false;
```

Error message: inaccessible due to its protected level

Comment: Did you create the listbox in SearchResultForm manually?

Comment: Yes, i created listbox Manually in SearchResultForm

Comment: Change your own classes to `public`. And what do you mean by 'form'? As long as I worked with WP8 I did not have any forms. What you see is called 'page'.  Are you using Xamarin Forms?

Comment: No i am using XAML To design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Parameter To your class SearchResultForm class here my class is showvideolbx

```
      public class showvideolbx
      {
         public ListBox SVListBox { get; set; }
      }
```

Assign ListBox Id to Class Parameter

```
     showvideolbx lbbox = new showvideolbx();
        lbbox.SVListBox = lbxSongsList;
```

Then Now You call the Create class and then ListBox Parameter as

```
     showvideolbx svlbox;
     if (svlbox.SVListBox.IsEnabled == false)
                svlbox.SVListBox.IsEnabled = true;
```

It will Work please try once.

Comment: Amazing answer Thanks Chinni

Comment: You really don't want to introduce another class in order to pass a reference.

Comment: Yes, it "will work", but it's a very bad and unnecessarily complex solution.

Comment: It would be much simpler, if you have exposed your ListBox as a property in *frmSearchResult*: `public ListBox formList { get {return listBox; } }`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your `listBox` is a `private` member  of `SearchResultForm`; that means it's not accessible from outside the `SearchResultForm` class. You can make make the `listBox` variable `public` or `internal`, but a better way do to it is to create a mutator method in the `SearchResultForm` class something like:

```
public void AddItemToListBox(string text) 
{
    listBox.Items.Add(text);
}
```

and then from your main form you will do:

```
  // Local object of SearchResultForm
SearchResultForm frmSearchResult = new SearchResultForm();
frmSearchResult.Show();
frmSearchResult.AddItemToListBox("test");
```

This way you can update the listBox without exposing your `SearchResultForm` class implementation details.

Comment: Hello Dan Dinu Thanks For Your Replay,  Please see the Question again it's Edited